# GoogleAuth access token is missing the userinfo.profile scope

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I have an android app that uses the Google Plus API and I also ask for an access token which I pass to my server so I can make oauth 2.0 API calls to get user details.
I ask for an access token using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` with the following scopes:

```
String scopes = "oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
                         https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
                         https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" ;
```

then, I pass the access token I get to my server, and make an api call to: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo`
which returns the following user details: `[id, email, verified, name, given_name, family_name, link, picture, gender, locale]`

so far so good. 
This works 90% of the time. Lately I've been getting users that don't have most of the details. When I examine their access token I see the following:

```
{
"issued_to": "534771845378-a8epgha85s5hkr3bqnsj8ihjvpl8pms.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"audience": "534771845378-ha8epgha85s5hkr3bqnsj8ihjvpl8pms.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"user_id": "103098746579631883577",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"expires_in": 3382,
"email": "***@***.com",
"verified_email": true,
"access_type": "offline"
}
```

Notice that the **userinfo.profile** scope is suddenly missing. Any thoughts on why this could happen on occasions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because more and more information is being stored in a Google+ Profile, which has different access controls, and not the older user profile.

You can get their **public** profile information with the plus.login scope using the https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me endpoint, but this will only be if they have made their information public. You will also not be able to get their email using this endpoint - you'll still need to use the oauth userinfo endpoint.

See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/ for further details and other available endpoints.